# General Advice to Creating a C++ Robot Template

Tags: c++, oop, templates, robotics

I'm working on a project that has evolved so many times, I've really started thinking about writing a generic class that controls other nested generic classes.

The issue is, I have so many ways I could go about it that I've become completely overwhelmed. I've reviewed vectors and template class examples, but I truly have no idea how to begin.

Let me explain,
I need to be able to use this template to create an object that I control directly.
The main, top level object, is the robot I'm working on documented here (Probably not helpful to read, included as reference):

```
Github: MiddleMan5/Onyx-BeagleBone which pulls from: 
Github: MiddleMan5/Project-Onyx-Quadruped
(New member 2-link restriction)
```

Which has the C++ Assembly.h file I'm working on making generic:
["Assembly File"](https://github.com/MiddleMan5/Onyx-BeagleBone/blob/master/include/Assembly.h)

Now I'm sorry if my syntax is a little rusty, I'm very new to C++ in a general sense. I have great difficulty with pointers, object vectors, etc.
I'm really just looking to be guided in a general direction of study, and less a "Fix my code!" answer.

Bear with me as I may mar C++ terms: 
I want to be able to create any type of robot configuration and manipulate EITHER it's individual assembly's End Effectors, or the entire chassis as a point particle physics object (if the robot is mobile).

This would allow me to use the same template to create a robot arm as well as my intended Quadruped. (Which is, in reality, a solid mobile mass that has a center and 4 "Arms"

Each initialized Robot must contain only one Body that in-itself contains at least one Base, one Joint, and one End Effector.

The creation of Top-Level object should fail if any of these things should fail to be included before Body.assemble creates the now-active robot. (`Body.assemble` creates `Chassis Onyx`)

I can now move the entire structure by saying something like `Onyx.Leg(1).move(X,Y)` or `Onyx.rotate(X,45); //Move all legs to satisy final body rotation angle`

Documented in my Brainstorming file here: [Please at least skim](https://github.com/MiddleMan5/Onyx-BeagleBone/blob/master/doc/Joints_Links_Bases.txt).
This file contains diagrams and the "definitions" I'm using to prototype pseudo-code.

I only want one "Robot".h and "Robot".cpp to define actions, movements, sizes, shapes, etc. and one Main.cpp to provide entry into the code. (Maybe I'm asking a bit much) but logically to me, this seems do-able.

Includes:

```
Main.cpp
        |_
        | Onyx.h
        |_Onyx.cpp //Body.move, body.rotate, body.raise
            |_Assembly.h To create the body as a combination of assemblies
```

Onyx as a quadruped looks like this:

```
ONYX Complete Diagram Example:
        EE          EE
        ||    __    ||
         |   |  |   |                      
         0__0+__+0__0
             _||_
         __0+_  _+  <-  0__
         0    \/          0  <-\
         |                |  <- - "Leg" and Body are two attached assemblies inside one complete containing Robot chassis          
        ||                || <-/
        EE                EE
```

Should be controlled like:

```
Onyx.EE1.moveTo(x,y);
```

or:

```
Onyx.moveTo(x,y);
```

Where I could further define gaits and parameters that would allow the robot ro take steps to move it's entire chassis to location (X, Y)

and has definitions for joints, links, and bases as such:

```
|Joint: Takes X and Y coordinates, rotates Link.            ----0----
|__ End Effector: A joint combined with an attached Link.   --------EE
|__ Base: A joint created that can be fixed statically through a link to another base joint
|   |__ Can be attached actively to a link and a joint 
|   |__ Can be used as a static reference to an assembly (Such as a leg) and attached to a joint on a different plane
|
|__ Primary Joint: the joint(s) that attach directly to the Body's base(s)

|Link: A length of physical mass between a joint.
|__Segment: two or more attached in-line links (multiple links combined at different angles can specify independent shapes or masses).
            Segments are useful for attaching spaced Bases. (Attach.Base(Segment1_2(End)); Segments can be attached either by their additive L1 or L2
```

I really am frustrated because the project has very quickly become way to complicated for me to even understand. This is why I was looking at creating a template. But it doesn't seem like accessing an object's object's method (Onyx.leg.move) is even possible in C++. Am I wrong?

If you actually read through to the end I want to give you a hand. Any advice you have on areas of study (Or advice to make my question clearer) would be GREATLY valued.

Thank You

Edit:
Okay, I went ahead and created a Class 'Assembly', which has methods to access a private subclass 'assemble' which attaches a "Leg with links n" to the assembly (god I need a different name) with subclass's Base, Link, and End_Effector. I guess I'm going to have to write individual methods and method handlers for each subclass of a subclass. This seems way to ugly and complicated with plenty of room to make errors.

The pseudo-flow as follows:

```
Assembly Onyx //Creates Robot: Onyx
Onyx.assemble(4, 3, 2); //Adds 4 legs each with 3 joints which includes 2 axis
for(i; 0 ---> 3)
Onyx.numleg_numL_length(i,1,114); //Defines L1 of Leg1 as 114mm
Onyx.numleg_numL_length(i,2,140); //Defines L2 of Leg1 as 114mm
```

and on and on and on and on.

Please tell me there's a simple trick that allows me to assign multiple variables to a named class instead of this infinite chain of methods functions and subclasses

Comment: One quick reaction is that it’s possible to access an object’s members’ methods if they’re public, but you don’t want to do this. A basic approach is that the robot has certain parts, and the code to translate a command into low-level motions should be part of the `Robot`class methods.  The legs should be `private` data. So, the class itself should be implementing `Onyx.moveTo(x,y)` by turning it into a bunch of commands like `legs[0].move()`. If you want the controller to be able to move individual legs, too, there should be a public interface like `Onyx.moveLeg(whichLeg, how)`.

Comment: @Lorehead I have provisions to statically create a leg of 3 servos with L1 and L2 connected to a base. From there I can calculate either the end effector's position relative to the base via Inverse Kinematics. This path, thus far, requires me to manually edit a Leg.h file and bind all the necessary variables. I guess I want a template class that can dynamically generate other classes? I really have lost my train of thought...

Comment: Okay, two pieces of advice.  One: there are really a lot of approaches that work, and you shouldn’t worry too much about finding the Right One.  Two: I don’t know a lot about this domain, but it seems like there are layers of abstraction from, “move to this location,” to “step forward with your left front leg,” to “extend your left front knee by 15°,” to “send these bits to the microcontroller.”  Those layers of abstraction seem like good candidates to use to determine which data and operations should be encapsulated into a single class that turns higher-level operations into lower-level ones.